# Getting error in webmatrix data while using mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webmatrix

[image]

I am getting this weird error. I am not currently connected to any database. I am 
working on MVC4.Can anybody help ?

Comment: Update your question. Could you show the code

Answer (score 0):

That is an exception in your ASP.NET web app. It is not related to ASP.NET, or MVC either. In turn it is a **file not loaded** error.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (System.IO.FileLoadException)

Above is the link to the MSDN post for this exception. You can learn by the name, that this exception is thrown, when the File is found, but is not loaded due to some error.

These errors are generally thrown for the Assembly files that are found in the application, but are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new class for example Fixup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

// this two lines are the important ones
namespace WebMatrix.Data { internal class Ignore { } }
namespace WebMatrix.WebData { internal class Ignore { } }
```